# Some VSCode Keybindings not working in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I have just started with VSCode on Ubuntu and was looking for the equivalent of `cmd+shift+D` in Sublime on the Mac (duplicate selected text) . According to [the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/keybindings) I should use `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+Down` or `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+Up` but these keybindings are not working for me. When I look in `File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts`, I see the definitions, but when I try to use them, nothing happens.

Comment: Unfortunately Windows-Users see different keybindings when they open the link. I think it's better to add the command id like `editor.action.insertLineBefore`.
However, maybe the shortcuts are overwritten globally? What happens when you define custom shortcuts for the commands you are looking for?

Comment: I have tried copying the definitions to my `keybindings.json` and the shortcuts still don't work. Interestingly though, if I change the shortcut to Ctrl+Shift+Down, it does work! I wonder if Ubuntu is confused (as I probably would be) by so many keys being pressed at the same time :)

Comment: I have same problem with Alt+Shift+Down (Shift key not working)!

Comment: Do you have a non-US keyboard where some keyboard codes are mapped to different key caps?

Answer (score 14):

Ubuntu uses those shortcuts for managing workspaces.

You can look for those keybindings in Settings -> Keyboard -> View and Customize Shortcuts

If there's nothing set to `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+*`, you can check `gsettings`

The following command should find shortcuts bonded to combinations with `Up` key:

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep Up
```

In my case there are those, which interfere with VS Code:

```
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-up ['<Control><Shift><Alt>Up']
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up ['<Control><Alt>Up']
```

The same goes with `Down` key.

### After all you can unset them by the following commands:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up "[]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down "[]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-up "[]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-down "[]"
```

In case you would want to reset them back to defaults:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-up
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-down
```

Answer (score 4):

upon checking my default keybinding, i found that **editor.action.insertCursorAbove**
and **editor.action.insertCursorDown** each has two keybindings
<kbd>ctrl+shift+up/down</kbd> and <kbd>alt+shift+up/down</kbd>.

so i changed **editor.action.copyLinesDownAction** and **editor.action.copyLinesUpAction** to <kbd>ctrl+shift+up</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl+shift+down</kbd> respectively. because in my ubuntu system <kbd>ctrl+shift+alt+up/down</kbd> keys were toggling the workspace.

Answer (score -1):

Ctrl+Shirt+up and Ctrl+Shirt+down will work.
Check your VS keyboard Shortcuts:
Click settings icon>keyborad shortcuts
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4HQy.png)