# VSCode split editor move file instead of copy

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have recently moved to Visual Studio Code and have a question that I have found an answer for.

When I split the editor it shows the focused file on both sides of the split.

I want the focused file to be moved with the split rather than showing a duplicate view.

Is there a setting or an extension that I can use to do this split / move?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try the `Move Editor into next Group` command:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+cmd+right",
  "command": "workbench.action.moveEditorToNextGroup"
}
```

Comment: That's not the same thing. If I have two groups already, and I'm on the left-hand group and do that, it'll move the editor into the right-hand group, whereas what I want — and what the question asks for — is creating a new split (so I would now have three) and moving the editor there. It's a third thing, distinct from "split and duplicate" and "move to next group". IntelliJ presents this action as "split and move {right,down}".

Comment: On my machine, if I have three open tabs and use the ctrl-alt-right combination, then one of two things happen. The first time, a new split is created and the active tab is moved to the newly created group. If I then select a tab from the previous group and press ctrl-alt-right it will be moved to the previously created group. Pressing ctrl-alt-right once more will create yet another group and move the tab to this new group, leaving me with three distinct groups, each containing one of the original three tabs. I would say this is more or less what you are talking about, @gimboland

Comment: I agree that these are not the same thing, however, this solves the issue for me. THANKS!
it's WIN + ALT + RIGHT for windows

Comment: @gimboland What I have done is to map "cmd+\" to both "move to next group" and "move to previous group" along with the when clauses `!multipleEditorGroups` and `multipleEditorGroups` respectively. That way, the same keyboard shortcut toggles an editor back and forth between split view.

Answer (score 15):

on `Windows`, `vscode v1.59.0`

To move file to **right** side
click on file to focus:
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>right arrow</kbd>


To move file to **left** side
click on file to focus:
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>left arrow</kbd>

Comment: If anybody is trying to do this in Ubuntu they should be aware that Ubuntu by default blocks that keybinding so it does not even get to Vscode.

Answer (score 12):

on mac default shortcut is:

control+command+ -> or <- arrow ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Personally, i always used ctrl+enter combination to open the next file in the side editor. So far, it is the most recommended way that I always use.

Answer (score 2):

In `Ubuntu` (20.04) the keybindings are the same as in windows:
`ctrl + alt + right` and `ctrl + alt + left` **however** gnome blocks these keybindings. In order to liberate them, run the following in the terminal which changes your gnome settings:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-left "[]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-right "[]"
```

After that, it should work.

See also:
[Some VSCode Keybindings not working in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33636531/some-vscode-keybindings-not-working-in-ubuntu)

And:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041914/something-blocks-ctrlaltleft-right-arrow-keyboard-combination

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/6197

Answer (score 0):

Windows: Ctrl-Alt-X

File -> Preferences -> Keyboard shortcuts.

Search "move editor" for wider set of options, or as in the attached image search "move editor into"

[image]