# Visual Studio Code in Ubuntu hotKey for copy Path of Active File

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, autokey

In Visual Studio Code (OS kUbuntu) is a hotKeys for

- copy Path of Active File
  configured but not works (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).

i also tried changed the hotkey to:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ü</kbd>
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>
3. <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>

every hotkey was possible to config in code but code ignores it. it looks good but do nothing if i use hotkey (works if i use mouse click):

[image: correct config]

at the end i needed to create a workaround written in autoKey:

```py
# script codeCopyPath_CtrlShictC
import time
keyboard.send_keys('<ctrl>+<shift>+a') # open the properties menu in studio code
time.sleep(.2)
keyboard.send_keys('copy Path of Active File<down><enter>')
```

that was the only way for me at the moment to have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for copy path.
Any idea for get it fixed better?
[image: autKeyConfig]

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.8
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.13.0-40-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1209140/vs-code-keyboard-shortcut-not-working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33636531/some-vscode-keybindings-not-working-in-ubuntu

Comment: yes this solves my problem: https://askubuntu.com/a/1269779/1017209

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Comment: In the future, when AutoKey appears to be misbehaving and staring at your code doesn't reveal the error, it's often helpful to run an AutoKey [trace](https://github.com/autokey/autokey-python2/wiki/Problem-Reporting-Guide) to see things from its point of view. The other thing to try is adding delays around the API calls, but you already did that. BTW, the time module is exposed by default, so you don't need to import it. It's a no op if you do.